# How to uninstall Appium desktop and its cache files from mac?

Tags: macos, appium, appium-desktop

I have trashed the older version of appium desktop (1.13) from application. Later on I installed the latest version of appium desktop (1.15).

When I started the appium server and click on appium inspector icon, I can still see the saved capabilities of previously installed appium desktop.

[image: Screenshot of saved capabilities]

How do I clean install the latest appium desktop?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the cached settings as well. Running the below command in a terminal will remove the Appium desktop's saved settings.

`rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/appium-desktop/Settings`